# Bootstrap 3: Icons are not showing

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 for my rails application. In view page the bootstrap icons were not showing.

My folder structures looks like.

```
 app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css

 app/assets/fonts/  ###font files

 app/assets/images/  ###image files
```

and inside bootstrap.min.css I am calling font-family as below

```
 @font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');src:url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg')}
```

Please correct me if I am doing it wrong.

UPDATE:

Code to show icons:

```
 <a title="edit" href="<%= edit_customer_customer_path(cust, from: "admin")%>">
 <i class="icon-pencil bigger-130"></i>
 </a>
```

Comment: Make sure you have your `glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot` and other files in `app/assets/fonts/` directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 uses different classes for icons, you are using `icon-*` classes which is for Bootstrap 2. In Bootstrap 3, you should use `.glyphicon` and `.glyphicon-*` CSS classes:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
```

See [Migrating to v3.x](http://getbootstrap.com/migration/).

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the structure based on the way you import the font and your project structure. Most probably there is an issue when you try to print an icon. May you post a snippet showing how you print the icons?

Update:
Based on your update with the code sample, it seems that you are using the Bootstrap 2 icons classes, while in 3 there is a font-family instead of the png sprites, so you should display the icons this way:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
```